# Gitflow for Visual Studio - cant find Git for Windows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, git-flow

Okay so I am trying to install the Gitflow extension for Visual Studio 2015 and getting it working properly.  After I install it and restart Visual Studio, I get this message in the Gitflow panel of Team Explorer:

"Could not locate Git for Windows on this machine.  This is required by Gitflow.  Please Install and try again"

I have attempted this multiple different ways and have not come up with any results.

Can somebody please provide me with a step-by-step process for how to get this working?  I am in charge of moving my team over from TFS to Git and most of the team members have only ever used TFS, so having something like Gitflow integrated into the IDE would be really helpful for overcoming the learning curve of a new source control system and a workflow

Comment: Did you install git? https://git-scm.com/downloads

Comment: yes, I installed Git, that didnt fix it.

Comment: At the command line, if you type `git` is it recognised as a command? If not, sounds like the path to the git installation hasn't been added to your system path variable.